# Pass-parameter when calling a function in Java

Tags: java, android, file, parameter-passing

in java, i'm calling a function which reads a text file's content from the web into a variable, but my problem is that the file's url is hardcoded in the functio. I would like to use this function several times for different files. So how can i manage, to add the file's url when i call the function?

The function is;

```
public class readtextfile extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>{

private TextView description;
public readtextfile(TextView descriptiontext){
    this.description = descriptiontext;
    }

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    URL url = null;
    String result ="";
    try {

        url = new URL("http://example.com/description1.txt");       
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
        String line = null;
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
        result+=line;
        }
        in.close();

        } 
        catch (MalformedURLException e) {e.printStackTrace();} 
        catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    return result;
}

 protected void onProgressUpdate() {
    //called when the background task makes any progress
 }

  protected void onPreExecute() {
     //called before doInBackground() is started
 }

@Override
 protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    this.description.setText(result); 
 }
  }
```

Where i'm calling the function:

```
public class PhotosActivity extends Activity {

    TextView description;
    String descriptiontext;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.photos_layout);

        description = ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.description1));

        new readtextfile(description).execute();
        }   

    }
```

Comment: you should read the documentation for AsyncTask before asking http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using AsyncTask for a single task is not a good solution, you should better look to `Threads`.

But if you want to use AsyncTask, anyway, you can add a constructor like this :

```
public readtextfile(TextView descriptiontext, String url){
    this.description = descriptiontext;
    this.url = url;
}
```

And use `this.url` in your doInBackground.

Comment: 'Using AsyncTask for a single task is not a good solution' - What??? If you make a single HTTP request or make a single DB query then using asyncTask is not good?

Comment: No, you should use Threads in that case. AsyncTask is generally for doing multiple tasks, between which you want to have action in the main threads. If your doInBackground will be called only once in your instance, you should use Threads instead.

Comment: just read the asynctask docs and see that what you are saying is simply not true: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: @gahfy was right, did you know that async tasks cant run in parallel ? if have 3 async tasks, Android will run them one by one, so if one of them take along time the other tasks will delayed. unlike threads.